# Using fftw3 inside a function produce segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fftw

Testing the following code I get the right answers:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
void dump_vector(float *a, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%f\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    float a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    dump_vector(a, 4);
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(2 * 2, a, a, FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    dump_vector(a, 4);
}
```

Result:

```
./main
1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    4.000000    
3.992188    4.501953    -334878449985782808576.000000   3.886292
```

But I want make a naive wrap for dct so:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
void dump_vector(float *a, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%f\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void dct(float * array, int xsize, int ysize)
{
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(xsize * ysize, array, array, FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
}


int main()
{
    float a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    dump_vector(a, 4);
    dct(a, 2, 2);
    dump_vector(a, 4);
}
```

Result:

```
./main
1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    4.000000    
3.992188    4.501953    -334878449985782808576.000000   3.886292    
[1]    10880 segmentation fault  ./main
```

Is there something that I am missing?

I need to do this because then I want to generate a `.so` file for using it in another app.

Comment: If your function modifies data inside the array `a` (I'm not familiar with `fftw3`, but it probably does), you can try passing its address (`&a`) to the wrapper call and dereferencing the pointer `**array` inside its definition.

Comment: The fftw library might be conflicting with other library you are using. Refer this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/51347/

Comment: Try to add the flag `FFTW_IN_PLACE` since the input array is also the output array. See http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html : default mode is `FFTW_OUT_OF_PLACE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is much simplier than expected: `fftw_plan_r2r_1d` perform DCTs/DSTs on arrays of **`double`**.

As is, the array `float a[]` is too small: 4 `float` are stored in 4x4=16 bytes, while `fftw_plan_r2r_1d` expects 4 `double` (32 bytes). Hence, `fftw_plan_r2r_1d` will attempt to read pass the end of the actual array. This triggers undefined behaviors such as segmentation fault or wrong results.

Two solutions:

- Change `float a[]` for `double a[]` and `dump_vector(float *a,...` for `dump_vector(double *a,...`
- Use `fftwf_plan_r2r_1d()` to build a `fftwf_plan` for arrays of `float`. See http://www.fftw.org/doc/Precision.html : the library `libfftw3f.a` must be linked by adding `-lfftw3f` to the compiler command.